# how to find a printing job status in java

Tags: java, zebra-printers, zpl

```
private void sendZPLContentToPrinter(String ipAddress, int portNumber, String zplContent) throws IOException {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
        socket.setSoTimeout(DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, portNumber), DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] zplBytes = zplContent.getBytes("UTF-8");
        outputStream.write(zplBytes);
        outputStream.flush();

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        throw new IOException("Connection timed out while trying to connect to the printer.");
    }
}
```

the above code will print the content.
now i want to know the printer job if it is successfull or not

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the Zebra SDK for Java, there is an example in the [javadocs](https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-12/webservices/content/com/zebra/sdk/printer/printerstatus).  (Copied here in case the link evaporates.)

```
package test.zebra.sdk.printer.examples;
 
 import com.zebra.sdk.comm.Connection;
 import com.zebra.sdk.comm.ConnectionException;
 import com.zebra.sdk.comm.TcpConnection;
 import com.zebra.sdk.printer.PrinterStatus;
 import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinter;
 import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinterFactory;
 import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException;
 
 public class PrinterStatusExample {
 
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Connection connection = new TcpConnection("192.168.1.100", TcpConnection.DEFAULT_ZPL_TCP_PORT);
         try {
             connection.open();
             ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);
 
             PrinterStatus printerStatus = printer.getCurrentStatus();
             if (printerStatus.isReadyToPrint) {
                 System.out.println("Ready To Print");
             } else if (printerStatus.isPaused) {
                 System.out.println("Cannot Print because the printer is paused.");
             } else if (printerStatus.isHeadOpen) {
                 System.out.println("Cannot Print because the printer head is open.");
             } else if (printerStatus.isPaperOut) {
                 System.out.println("Cannot Print because the paper is out.");
             } else {
                 System.out.println("Cannot Print.");
             }
         } catch (ConnectionException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
             connection.close();
         }
     }
 }
```

The code is self-explanatory.

For information on performing other tasks, take a look at the javadocs' [overview page](https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-12/webservices/content/overview-summary).

Comment: outputStream.write(zplBytes);

the above line will issue the print, just after that i want to find it the print job is successful or not

Comment: do i need to add any dependency

Comment: 1) Look at the javadocs to see if there is a way to get exactly what you want.  Otherwise, adapt the above code.   2) Read the overview page.  Basically yes ... though I didn't read to see if they have mavenized it.

Comment: can i download the jar from somewhere?

Comment: i have downloaded the jar from git hub and added it in my project

Comment: Aravind: research first, and again.  Then ask.

Comment: the project is working fine after add the jar in my project but after generate the jar,
i tried to run it via cmd but some exception is coming what should i do

Comment: You haven't provided any information that would help us to help you.  So, I will just point you at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ... so that you can learn to help yourself.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>your.groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>external-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2800</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/ZSDK_API.jar</systemPath>
            <type>jar</type>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for your.groupId:external-library:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/ZSDK_API.jar @ line 77, column 25